# Cannot create 2 functions outside main

Tags: c++, function

I've started C++ not too long ago, and I have problems understanding why I can'T seem to be able to create two functions outside my main.  When I only have 1, all is good, the second I add the second one, which is the Far one, tell me to put a ; after my cel function declaration...

```
// Lab03.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    double celcius(int);
    double far(int);
    std::cout<<"DEGREE DE FAR A CEL\n";
    for (int i=32; i<213; i++)
    {
        std::cout.precision(3);
        std::cout<<i<<"F = " <<celcius(i)<<"C      ";

        if ((i+1)%4==0)
        {
            std::cout<<"\n";
        }

        std::cout<<"\n\n\nDEGREE DE CEL A FAR\n";
        for (int i=0; i<101; i++)
        {
            std::cout.precision(3);
            std::cout<<i<<"C = " <<far(i)<<"C      ";

            if ((i+1)%4==0)
            {
                std::cout<<"\n";
            }
        }
        _gettch();
        return 0;
    }

    double celcius(int n)
    {
        double endcel;
        endcel= (n-32.0)*(5.0/9.0);
        return endcel;
    }

    double far(int o)
    {
        double endfar=(o*(9/5))+32;
        return endfar;
    }
```

Comment: Are you missing a closing brace at the end of main? Rather, I don't think you're closing off your first for loop with a closing brace.

Comment: Most likely, if you indent your code, you will see the error yourself. Indent and format it anyway so that we have a chance to spot the error. also, add the actual compiler output, not only your interpretation of the error message (you're omitting line and column numbers)

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you're missing an end } to close your main function just prior to the celcius function.

Proper code indentation will help you find problems like this in the future.

```
// Lab03.cpp : Defines the entry point for the console application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    double celcius(int);
    double far(int);
    std::cout<<"DEGREE DE FAR A CEL\n";
    for (int i=32; i<213; i++) {
        std::cout.precision(3);
        std::cout<<i<<"F = " <<celcius(i)<<"C      ";
        if ((i+1)%4==0) {
            std::cout<<"\n";
        }
        std::cout<<"\n\n\nDEGREE DE CEL A FAR\n";
        for (int i=0; i<101; i++) {
            std::cout.precision(3);
            std::cout<<i<<"C = " <<far(i)<<"C      ";
            if ((i+1)%4==0) {
                std::cout<<"\n";
            }
        }
        _gettch();
        return 0;
    }
}

double celcius(int n) {
    double endcel;
    endcel= (n-32.0)*(5.0/9.0);
    return endcel;
}

double far(int o) {
    double endfar=(o*(9/5))+32;
    return endfar;
}
```